Unknown GPS coordinate decimal format with too many integer digits
In a dashcam video, in what seems to be a country with a Slavic language, I can see a coordinate string

N4313.1947E13202.2535

Punctuation and (lack of) spaces are reproduced as in the original.
This does not appear to match any of the standard formats mentioned in Wikipedia or accepted by Google. In particular, the four- and five-digit integer parts seem too large for the otherwise fitting decimal format. Inserting degree/minute/second markers in plausible places results in a location in the middle of the Black Sea.
Is this a known format, or does anybody know how to decode it?

"Inserting degree/minute/second markers in plausible places results in a location in the middle of the Black Sea" Which places did you try? If I try 43°13.1947N 132°02.2535E in Google Earth, I arrive somewhere North from Vladivostok (although not quite on a road, but in the woods...).

Maybe this format is a conversion from hex value coordinates like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45607836
If this is the case, then it could also be read as 43°13'19.47"N 132°02'25.35"E, which is at the end of a road, where it seems to continue as a dirt track. Could it fit the location viewed in the video?

it may be in utm projected system
